# Why Does My Hashmap Not Register (Work)

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

Sorry if the title does not explain this enough because I am fairly new.

Simply what is happening is I want to register a recipe (See code Below). Then I want to check  whether the input recipe matches a registered recipe. I am doing this via hashmaps and arrays.

```
public static Integer CraftRecipe(int item1, int item2, int item3, int item4, int item5, int item6){

    int[] recipeFormatter =  new int[]{item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6};
    int[] recipeInput = recipeFormatter;        
    Recipe.put(recipeInput, 7);

    if (Recipe.containsKey(recipeInput)){
        System.out.println("Recipe Worked");
        return Recipe.get(recipeInput);
    } else {            
        System.out.println("Recipe Failed");            
        return null;            
    }       
}
```

So my problem is the registered recipe doesn't come up when I test for it. Am I doing something wrong with hashmaps, arrays methods and if so how could I achieve the result I want?

Comment: What is the type of Recipe? Can you post it's source code?

Comment: Yes. Do not store direct arrays in `Map` (in general).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use arrays (`Object[]` or `int[]` or another) as key for your `Map` because arrays don't override `hashCode` nor `equals` method.

If you *have to* use an array as your key, use a `List` instead, easily achievable by using [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-). But this falls for arrays of primitive types, because this method will threat them as a single `Object`. In code:

```
int[] fooArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int[]> fooList = Arrays.asList(fooArray);
//fooList contains a single element which is fooArray
```

So you should use wrapper classes for this:

```
Integer[] fooArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Integer> fooList = Arrays.asList(fooArray);
//fooList contains 3 elements: 1, 2, 3
```

IMO you should not use a collection as a key in a `Map` unless it's a specific requirement. Instead, I'll try to search for other options.